# UIViewController external assignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that contains a field `x`. Based on the value of `x`, the `UIViewController` can have different interface.

Now, I want to ask the external assignment `viewController.x = x1` will happen before or after `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `awakeFromNib`?

For example:

```
CustomViewController vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomViewController"];
vc.x = x1;
```

or

```
CustomViewController vc = [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController" bundle:nil];
vc.x = x1;
```

Comment: why did I got a minus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The external assignment will happen before viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and all view... functions.
But after initWithNibName and so on. initWithNibName is the initialization of the view, so it will be executed before.

If you need different interfaces depending on x, why don't you do it in initialization?

```
if(x == ...) {
    CustomViewController vc = [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController1" bundle:nil];
} else {
    CustomViewController vc = [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController2" bundle:nil];
}
```

Anyway, try some breakpoints and you will see the execution order.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to create 2 CustomViewControllers. Because the difference between 2 view controller is not so big

Comment: It is the same view controller with different nib files.

Comment: Yes, I mean nib files. The x value can define several different interfaces. (more than 2)

Comment: So you can do it as I suggested, or not?

Comment: No, but thanks to your answer about when the assignment happens.

Answer (score 0):

have both constructors as static methods of the view controller

I believe that you already know the value of x when you init the view controller so you can call the correct constructor before:

```
+ (CustomeViewController*)createFromNib {
    return [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController" bundle:nil];
}

+ (CustomeViewController*)createFromStoryBoard {
    UIStoryboard *mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myStoryBoardName" bundle:nil];
    return [mystoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomViewController"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` et al will not be called until the `UIViewController` is pushed/presented onto the `UINavigationController` view controller stack for the first time.